# Portable method for encrypting a usb partition that works on Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, usb, security, encryption

I am looking for a good (and secure) way to encrypt a single partition of a USB-drive that will work for both, Windows and Linux systems. At the moment I have a 64GB USB 3.0 that is split up into 3 partitions.

1: 25GB NTFS. Pure Storage, needs to be the first partition so Win-Pcs mount it properly.

2: 4GB ext3 Linux Live System.

3: 30GB luks encrypted ext3 - used as a persistent storage for the live system.

I hope you can tell, where I am trying to go with this. Having my PC fit into my wallet whilst also having a decent mobile storage. And this mobile storage (so partition 1) is, what I would like to have encrypted since I am afraid of losing this drive and the sensitive information on it. (It happened) So partition 1 needs to be encrypted, readable by Linux and Windows distros and without having any extra programs installed on either systems.

I am new to encryption, so can anyone help me please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: LUKS or Truecrypt (or a derivative / successor). Portable - not so sure, but if you're not running your own OS you're just asking to be infected / scanned / corrupted / your data to be copied by some foreign OS

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking the time to reply to my question. I know about LUKS and TrueCrypt but the problem is that I explicitly need a portable solution (luks wouldn't be any problem on Linux but it is on Windows). You're saying that I'm asking to be infected, scanned or corrupted by some foreign os...Could you explain that further? I don't quite get what you mean.

Comment: Maybe I can't really tell where you're trying to go with this... If you're not allowed to install any programs or run as root, then you're not running your own OS on your own drive, correct? So you're running on someone else's computer with their OS, which could be infected with any malware, and they could be logging all data & keystrokes as well. Any drives connected to such a computer could be read & copied, and infected too. *If* you were running your own OS, booted from your USB or DVD, it would be much less likely to be monitored/infected.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I tried to do. But never mind, I chose to solve my question with VeraCrypt (does not actually solve it, but close enough) Thanks again!